# Play! Framework composing actions with async web request

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm quite new to Scala
I'm trying to access Instagram API from Play! and Scala.

```
def authenticate = Action {
request =>
  request.getQueryString("code").map {
    code =>
      WS.url("https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token")
        .post(
        Map("client_id" -> Seq(KEY.key), "client_secret" -> Seq(KEY.secret), "grant_type" -> Seq("authorization_code"),
          "redirect_uri" -> Seq("http://dev.my.playapp:9000/auth/instagram"), "code" -> Seq(code))
      ) onComplete {
        case Success(result) => Redirect(controllers.routes.Application.instaline).withSession("token" -> (result.json \ "access_token").as[String])
        case Failure(e) => throw e
      }
  }
 Redirect(controllers.routes.Application.index)
```

}

When app executes, the last redirect happens before redirect in case of Success.
Tell me please, how to avoid it. And Also, let me know about bad practices that is in my code.

Comment: try using the Await companion object for waiting to finish:  Await.ready($futurevar, Duration.Inf)

Comment: Never, ever use Await.ready, Await.result or Await.anything in a Play app.  You will run into deadlocks and all sorts of other things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With Play, you return a result - you don't send a result.  The `onComplete` method attaches a method that does something, but doesn't return anything (note its return value is `Unit`, ie, `void`).  After attaching that callback, you are then returning `Redirect` on the last line, which is not what you want to do.  Instead you want to `map` the future that you get back from the WS invocation, and return that future.  And to return a future in Play, you need to use the `Action.async` builder.  eg:

```
def authenticate = Action.async { request =>

  request.getQueryString("code").map { code =>

    WS.url("https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token").post(
      Map(
        "client_id" -> Seq(KEY.key),
        "client_secret" -> Seq(KEY.secret),
        "grant_type" -> Seq("authorization_code"),
        "redirect_uri" -> Seq("http://dev.my.playapp:9000/auth/instagram"),
        "code" -> Seq(code)
      )
    ).map { result =>

      Redirect(controllers.routes.Application.instaline)
        .withSession("token" -> (result.json \ "access_token").as[String])

    }
  }.getOrElse {
    Future.successful(Redirect(controllers.routes.Application.index))
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand this technique, what's the point of an 'Async' action, if the action is executed synchronously and the user redirected after the action?

Comment: async in this case is referring to threads/asynchronous io. The creation of the result is not created synchronously by the thread that handles the request, rather, that thread returns immediately without performing any IO (so it can do other work for other requests), and the creation of the result is done asynchronously in another thread when the call to the instagram API completes.