# why scala method didn't work in a Line-by-Line sequence?

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm going to achieve a simple method about login authentication. validate is a POST route

```
def validate: play.api.mvc.Action[play.api.mvc.AnyContent] = Action { 
    implicit request ⇒
      var isSuccess: Some[Boolean] = Some(false)
      val data = login_Form.bindFromRequest().get
      models.user.validate(data.name, data.psd).map(ccc =>
        if (ccc) {
          Logger.info("1.1")
          isSuccess = Some(true)
        } else {
          Logger.info("1.2")
          isSuccess = Some(false)
        }
      )
      if (isSuccess.get) {
        Logger.info("2.1")
        Ok(views.html.index.render())
      } else {
        Logger.info("2.2")
        Ok(views.html.login("Login failed"));
      }
}
```

models.user.validate return a Future(Boolean), but it didn't make my idea come true. The logs just print 2.2 and then can not login. I don't know what's my problem. I do this in Play2.4, Scala 2.11.7, sbt 0.13.8, and run the application in typesafe Activator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Future will be resolved in the future.

As such, the code you run on it (in `map`) does not execute immediately.

You have to either

- move the `Ok` call into the `map` as well (and have your method [return a `Future[Result]` instead of the `Result` directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20252970/play-framework-composing-actions-with-async-web-request)), or
- `Await.result` your booolean (to block the call, waiting for the validate call to complete)

Other observations:

- why is `isSuccess` optional (not not just a simple `Boolean`)?
- don't use `var` unless you really have to. Prefer to assign the resolved value to a `val` once you know it instead of initializing a `var` with a temporary placeholder.
- avoid calling `get`, better handle the case where data is missing as well

---

Untested rewrite:

```
def validate = Action.async { implicit request ⇒
  login_Form.bindFromRequest() match {
     case Some(data) => models.user.validate(data.name, data.psd).map(okay =>
      if (okay) {
         Logger.info("1.1")
         Ok(views.html.index.render())
      } else {
         Logger.info("1.2")
         Ok(views.html.login("Login failed"));
      }
    )
    case None =>
       Future.successful(Ok(view.html.login("Invalid form posted"))
  }
}
```

Comment: i do it in Eclipse ,the rewrite didn't work. Show me a exception :    [type mismatch; found : scala.concurrent.Future[play.api.mvc.Result] required: play.api.mvc.Result] in okay

Comment: did you use Action.async ? The method is no longer returning the Result, it returns a Future[Result] now (that will resolve once "validate" is done).

Comment: You need something like AsyncAction, and try not to use Await, just chain the future and perform transformation, more about Future at http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20252970/play-framework-composing-actions-with-async-web-request